# ListBox SelectedIndex always -1 in slectedindexchanged event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

In the sample code there are two listboxes. In ListBox1 the items are defined in Default.aspx. In ListBox2 they are defined in the codefile. ListBox1 behaves as expected, the text box is updated whenever an item is selected. When ListBox2 triggers an event the selectedindex is always -1.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lb1_OnSelectedIndexChanged"     AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lb1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> ab = new List<string>();
        ab.Add("a");
        ab.Add("b");
        ListBox2.DataSource = ab;
        ListBox2.DataBind();

        ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(lb1_OnSelectedIndexChanged);
        ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(lb2_OnSelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    protected void lb1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }

    protected void lb2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The list of items has been moved to Default.aspx to get it working, but I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong with this. -- Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't databind ListBox2 on every page load. Try:

```
Page_Load()...
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
       //databind listbox2
   }
}
```

Try reading up a bit on the ASP.NET page lifecycle. On the postback, the ListBox2 will have it's correct state due to viewstate.

Your current code resets it. Hence the -1.